# ShellExecuteEx Does Not Work Stable

Tags: c++, winapi, access-violation, c++builder-6

I'm trying to install windows service (Build with CBuilder 6) using [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here is my install function.

```
int WinServiceInstall(WideString ServicePath)
{
 int result = 0;
 LPCWSTR filename = L"MyService.exe";
 LPCWSTR params = L"/install /silent";
 LPCWSTR dir = ServicePath;

 WideString fullPath = ServicePath+"\\"+filename;
 if (!PathFileExistsW(fullPath.c_bstr())) return -1;

 SHELLEXECUTEINFOW *lpExecInfo = new SHELLEXECUTEINFOW();
 try
 {
     lpExecInfo->cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW);
     lpExecInfo->hwnd = 0;
     lpExecInfo->lpVerb = NULL;
     lpExecInfo->lpFile = filename;
     lpExecInfo->lpDirectory = dir;
     lpExecInfo->lpParameters = params;
     lpExecInfo->nShow = SW_HIDE;
     lpExecInfo->hInstApp = NULL;
     BOOL bResult = ShellExecuteExW(lpExecInfo);
     WaitForSingleObject(lpExecInfo->hProcess,INFINITE);
     if (!bResult)
     {
       int ErrorCode = GetLastError();
       WideString message = GetLastErrorMessage(ErrorCode);
       message +="\n"+IntToStr(ErrorCode);
       MessageBoxW(0,message,L"GetLastError",0);
       PrintError(ErrorCode);
       result = -1;
     }
 }
 catch(Exception &e)
 {
   printf("Hata: %s",e.Message);
   result = -1;

   WideString message = e.Message;
   MessageBoxW(0,message,L"Exception",0);
 }
 delete lpExecInfo;
 return result;
}
```

But ShellExecuteEx function don't work stable.

Sometimes throwing EAccessViolation exception.

How can I do debug problem ? Where's my mistake ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you initialize COM before invoking ShellExecuteExW?

Comment: The Windows API does not throw C++ exceptions. Are you using any compiler extensions that allow you to catch SEH exceptions standard C++ syntax? Irrespective of that, since you don't appear to need any shell support here anyway, why don't you just use `CreateProcess` instead of a game of Russian Roulette?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't use any compiler extension.

Comment: @Asesh I'm not used com initialize.

Comment: Semi off topic but feedback on your code: Please learn to use [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)

Comment: @Asesh I'm trying now com initialize.

Comment: Semi off topic: why don't you use `SHELLEXECUTEINFOW ExecInfo; ...; ExecInfo.` instead of `SHELLEXECUTEINFOW *lpExecInfo = new SHELLEXECUTEINFOW();; ...; lpExecInfo->` ? Allocating a `SHELLEXECUTEINFOW` on the stack just to delete it at the end of the function is completly pointless.

Comment: @MichaelWalz **heap** you meant. Any perhaps it is for initialization. But that is best done like so: `SHELLEXECUTEINFOW execInfo = { sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW) };`

Comment: You need to check the return value before waiting on the handle. And yes, why would you use `ShellExecuteEx` here at all? You are just asking for trouble.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks, of course I meant __heap__ and not __stack__.

Comment: `lpExecInfo->hProcess` will always be NULL unless you add the flag `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` to your `lpExecInfo->fMask`.  You should check `bResult` and make sure `lpExecInfo->hProcess` is valid before pasing it to `WaitForSingleObject`.  You will also need to close it with `CloseHandle` when finished.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want to start process and wait for complete.

Comment: Yes. I know. So many questions. Why are you not checking the return value immediately? Why didn't you pass `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`? Why are you leaking the handle? Why aren't you using `CreateProcess`? You don't understand these functions well enough to use them. Spend more time reading the documentation and learning. Coding when you don't know what you are coding against never ends well. Stop guessing.

Comment: If you want to start the process and wait for it to terminate then you should use CreateProcess instead. It's easier to use that API

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you're right.
I will consider your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is with CreateProcess.

```
bool WinServiceInstall(WideString ServicePath)
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

    WideString lpCommandLine=L"\""+ServicePath+"\\MyService.exe"+"\" /install /silent";

    if(CreateProcessW(NULL,
        lpCommandLine,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi )
    )
    {
        WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
        CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
        CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        wchar_t buf[256];
        long errorCode = GetLastError();
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, errorCode,MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), buf, 256, NULL);
        MessageBoxW(0,buf,L"Error",0);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP's convention of representing a boolean with the `int` values `0` and `-1` is not really worth repeating, IMHO. Ditto for the naming convention. I'd write a wrapper for him, but would use a normal `bool` for the main function.

Comment: Second argument needs to be modifiable and you supply const

Comment: I'm fixing it now.

Comment: Passing `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` to `FormatMessageW` means, that you are not in control of the message returned. In that case you should really also pass `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` along (see [The importance of the FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS flag](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071128-00/?p=24353)).